# New to C++ constructors : why is the output of this program 1 2 and not 1 0 2 0

Tags: c++, class, constructor-overloading

why is the constructor Number() not being invoked when a number data type is initialized without any values ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number {

   int n;
   public:
      Number() {
          cout<< 0 << " ";    
      }
      Number(int i): n(i) {
          cout<< n << " ";
      }
};

int main()
{
  int i = 1;
  Number n1();
  Number *n2 = new Number(i++);
  Number *n3;
  new Number(i++);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Number n1();` is a function declaration. And there are plenty of dupes for these like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384406/what-does-static-testclass-testclass-do-in-c/73384518#73384518.

Comment: `Number n1();` -> `Number n1;` The first declares a function, the second declares a variable.

Comment: sorry to say, but it is the [most vexing parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You can switch to initializer-list style declaration to avoid such issue - `Number n1{};`